# Dynamically recreated TextBox Value in Page_PreInit dependent on value of HiddenField

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, textbox

I create some dynamic controls eg: `TextBox`. 
These a created in a `ModalPopupExtender` and are created after a ButtonClick.

```
protected void AddGroupBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   GroupMPE.Show();//GroupMPE is a ModalPopupExtender 
   ScheduleIdHF.Value = 1; //ScheduleIdHF is a HiddenField declared in the .aspx page
   CreateControls(ScheduleIdHF.Value);
   ...
}
private void CreateControls(string ScheduleId)
{
    TableRow TR = new TableRow();
    TR.ID = "tableRow1";
    TableCell TC = new TableCell();
    TC.ID = "tableCell1;
    TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
    textBox.ID = "textBox1";
    TC.Controls.Add(textBox);
    TR.Cells.Add(TC);
    ExampleTable1.Rows.Add(TR);//ExampleTable1 is declared in the .aspx page

}
```

Then when another button is clicked I want to recreate these controls on `Page_PreInit` like this.

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(IsPostBack)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ScheduleIdHF.Value))
            {
                CreateControls(ScheduleIdHF.Value);
                ...
```

However I want the method call to CreateControls to be conditional on and using the value of the `HiddenField` ScheduleIdHF. The problem is that the `HiddenField` is null and is not created to after the `Page_PreInit` event. Does anybody have any solutions to solve this conundrum? Because I want to get the text of the `TextBox` after postback.

Comment: I don't think that it is possible. See docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Comment: Just posted an answer. It's quite simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Session variable to store the value of the HiddenField and then retrieve it in the PreInit event, like:

```
        protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            string ScheduleIdHF = string.Empty;
            if (Session["ScheduleIdHF"] != null)
            {
                ScheduleIdHF = Session["ScheduleIdHF"].ToString();
                CreateControls(ScheduleIdHF);
                ...
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I gave you an upvote and accepted your answer as it was a good one.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily access the textbox/hiddenfield value using the following code. This is just using basic web programming idea that anything posted to server is available in `Request` object.

**Code-behind to access control values in PreInit event**

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(Page.IsPostBack) {
       var x = Request[TextBox1.UniqueID];
       var y = Request[ScheduleIdHF.UniqueID];
       //use values of x and/or y to implement your logic
       if(y != null && y == "somevalue") {
          //your custom logic goes here
       }
   }
}
```

**Textbox markup**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:HiddenField ID="ScheduleIdHF" runat="server"  Value="1010"/>
```

Comment: I gave you an upvote but I accepted @Ernesto Rodriguez Lucas's answer as it suited my needs more. Your answer was a good answer though.

Comment: No problems.  Just remember that if the hidden field value is changed on client-side by JavaScript then the Session variable approach will not work.  So,  in my view, its not a good solution since it does not always work.  Also,  Session variables consume extra memory  on a per user basis, which is not good for an ASP.Net app; you should always try to minimize memory consumption in your app. On the other hand, the Request variable approach does not consume any extra memory on a per user basis and works always even when hidden field value is changed by JavaScript.

Comment: Also, if you have to use the Session variable approach, make sure you set the Session variable in Page_PreRender event which fires towards the end of page lifecycle, else you could end up with hard to debug issues.